# Directory trees merging tool

Tags: windows, software-rec

I have two directory trees - the damaged one and a backup/outdated one. I need a windows tool which will compare them up to files dates and content and show me a list of differences. Could you recommend me one?

Answer (score 1):

[Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) does exactly this, and it does it very well.

It can also be used for comparing files. (Like WinDiff)